# Тире в списке

Tags: html, css

```
<h3>Список</h3>
<ul>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
    <li>текст</li>
</ul>
```

Пример:
 — текст

Как сделать нормальное тире в списке?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

ul li:before {
    content:  "—";
    position: relative;
    left:     -5px;
}
```

[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/gP6ss/)

Answer (score 1):

```
li{list-style-type:"– ";}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а какой вы ожидаете развернутый ответ увидеть??? Все остальные тоже оставили только стили в качестве ответа. Что за избирательность?

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0
    }
ul li{
       position: relative;
      }
ul li:before {
        content:  "—";
        position: absolute;
        left:     -18px;
    }
```

Немного изменил вид